# How to reduce generic object structure without "any"?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get rid of the `any` type in the reducer. Already tried a lot, but it keeps complaining about something every time.

*data.json*

```json
{
  "login": {
    "form": {
      "username": "Username",
      "password": "Password",
      "submit": "Login"
    }
  }
}
```

*index.ts*

```js
import values from "./data.json" assert { type: "json" };

interface MagicF {
  <T>(data: T): (scope?: string) => (key: string) => string;
}

const getter: MagicF =
  jsonData =>
  (scope = "") =>
  key =>
    scope
      .split(".")
      .concat(key.split("."))
      .filter(a => a)
      .reduce(
        // how do i get rid of this any type?
        (section: any, key) =>
          section[key] ||
          `[unknown key "${key}"${scope ? ` in scope "${scope}"` : ""}]`,
        jsonData
      );

console.log(getter<typeof values>(values)("login")("form.username"));
console.log(getter(values)("login")("form.password"));
console.log(getter(values)()("login.form.username"));
console.log(getter(values)()("login.form.password"));
console.log(getter(values)("login.form")("password.typo"));
console.log(getter(values)("login.form")("password"));
console.log(getter(values)("login")("form"));
```

I want to have everything I need in the interface, or at least not with `any` typing.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing. That would at least mean defining `values` for us instead of importing it from something we can't access.

Comment: @jcalz done, added json example

Comment: that wont work unless you specify the input data type more precisely (e.g. potentially recursive record). on the other hand, why not just use lodash/get ?

Comment: Thanks. Now that I can look at it: for this to be a [mre] you shouldn't have any distractions that don't have to do with your question, and right now there's a big one: your `MagicF` says that its input is of type `T` and it returns a `T | string`.  But that isn't true at all: `const x = getter(values)("login")("form"); if (typeof x !== "string") { console.log(x.login.form.password); }` will be a runtime error but the compiler is happy because it thinks `x` the same type as `values`. Could you fix this or remove it so that people can focus on the `any` issue?

Comment: (See prev comment) If I try to fix it by defining an appropriate-ish `JSONValue` type, then I get [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3qDEw) which checks `section` and `key` and then indexes.  But I don't know if that meets your needs because I don't know if my `JSONValue` is even close to what you're going for.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: It looks good on first glance. Also, thanks about the runtime error thingy. I had hoped I could avoid having to create a manual JSONValue type, but if that's what it takes, i guess in can live with it. Thanks :)

Comment: actually, if there was one thing i'd like to add, it's adding `JSONValue[]` to the `JSONValue` definition, but then it runs into an issue again. [see here](https://shorturl.at/tBQV9)

Comment: I'd do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBdb4W).  But could you please do as I asked and fix the `T` thing so it's not a distraction? I'm not sure how I'm supposed to write an answer if there's a whole section about how you absolutely do not expect the ultimate output of `MagicF` to be the same type as its input.  I'd be happy to write up an answer after that.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is that you always get a string back, no matter what. if the final result is not one, there should be a fallback in the reducer. The T was just a leftover from my failed attempts. :D

Comment: And yet it remains in the question. Could you [edit] to remove it? Or do you mind if I do the edit myself?

Comment: by any means, feel free to, I got what I needed :) thanks

Comment: I edited so it's just `string` but now the code isn't a [mre] because some calls don't produce a `string` (e.g., `getter(values)("login")("form")`). It's great that you got what you needed, but SO is meant to be a resource for future readers as well. Could you [edit] to put the "fallback in the reducer" that ensures everything is a string? How shall we proceed? I could try to edit the question myself, but that's primarily your responsibility here because you're the one who knows what you meant by "there should be a fallback in the reducer".